# Custom list template not showing up in Sharepoint Designer to create

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I created a custom list on my main SP site and saved it as a custom list template.

When I go to a sub-site, using SP Designer, and click on "Lists and Libraries" and then go to the Ribbon to click "Sharepoint List" (In the "New" area), I expected to see my custom list but it was not there.

If I go to the sub-site through a browser and click on "Site Actions" > "More Options" to "Create" a list, the custom list shows up there. But that sort of defeats the point of using SPD to me.

And I'm thinking the answer that I should create a Site Template to import those custom lists in order to see them in designer is also counter intuitive.

Sorry if this is a real basic question (new to SP), but why won't my custom list show up as an option to create in SP Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Dude. SPD cannot show the existing custom lists in "new area". Hence you cannot see them on SPD Ribbon "Sharepoint List" (In the "New" area). SPD allows you to do lot of stuff which you cannot do using your SP site in the browser.